# pyinstaller causes me error when using pandas library

Tags: pandas, pyinstaller

I have trouble getting an executable when using the pandas library.
A simple script like:

```
import pandas
print ('Hello world')
```

I get the following error in the cmd

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I don't know why it is when I remove the pandas library, the executable is created without any errors